# Setting up the "mate" command in bash

Tags: bash

Attempting to setup bash so I can call the "mate" command to edit text files. After running this line, the link appears to exist but I'm still getting "mate: command not found"

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate/mate
```

- Textmate is installed in applications
- using OSX Mountain Lion
- directory structure is in place

Comment: Is it really ~/bin/mate/mate? I'd expect that to be ~/bin/mate

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the shell support in textmate preferences. Follow these steps.

- Open textmate
- Open Preferences via your top menu TextMate > Preferences or pressing Command + ,
- Click on Terminal tab
- Click the install button

note: This will install the command line support to your bash file by default. If you are not using bash, you'll need to add the following line to your shell or select the correct path from the dropdown menu. Once you reload your terminal, this will load the path to the EDITOR variable.

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

make sure you reload your shell config by using source like this

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

check that your EDITOR variable has been loaded with this command

```
echo $EDITOR
```

Don't know what shell you are using? You can use the echo command to show the result of your $SHELL variable like this

```
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: had to do the explicit entry for `export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"` in `~/.bashrc`; seems default path loading doesn't work anymore on some systems (mine was **macOS 10.14.2**). Nevertheless, nice piece!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alias mate='/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate'
```

Put it in your ~/.bashrc file if you want to use it in every terminal session.

I have a feeling that the problem with your symlink solution is that ~/bin is in your PATH, but ~/bin/mate/ is not, so try alternatively:

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate ~/bin/mate
```

### Edit:

Removed the tilde before `Applications`, `Applications` is in the root not in the home directory.

Comment: not having any luck with those suggestions. It's been suggested that I add this:

'export EDITOR="mate -w"

export PATH=~/bin:$PATH'
to my .bashrc, but that's not workin either.

Comment: Did you source ~/.bashrc after adding in the new lines? Also, what is the actual path to launch Textmate from the command line in your environment? (i.e. where is the binary actually stored?)

Comment: Apologies, i'm a bit of a noob on this. I'm attempting part 2 of the bash course on peepcode.com and the instructor uses the "mate" command in his tutorials while setting up his environment so I'm attempting to set mine up so I can mimic his actions...

I punched 'source ~/.bashrc' into the command line (and also refreshed the terminal window) and then attempted to use the mate command on the known location of a text file. Is that what you meant for me to do?

Also, I think the binary location is here: /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate

Comment: Try the updated answers. Also try to see if you can launch the application from commandline with: ~/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate

Comment: ~/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate
failed too, (No such file or directory)
but The program works when i open it from dock or finder... strange

Comment: Remove the tilde from the call, Applications is not in your home directory but in the root directory. However I would go for the alias defined in ~/.bashrc instead of the symlink.

Comment: @sampson-chen - when setting your `$PATH`, you should probably use the `$HOME` variable instead of a tilde.  So: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this and it worked fine for me on Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) and TextMate (1.5.11 r1635) installed in `Applications`.

It seems like you no longer need to create aliases/symbolic links to access the TextMate shell utility from command line. Instead, `mate` by default is installed in `/usr/bin`.

In Terminal, go to `/usr/bin` and list the files there. Do you see `mate` over there? If not, check `/usr/local/bin`.

If you didn't see `mate` in either of the folders above, try removing and installing again. I just tried a fresh installation and `mate` worked out of the box for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about OSX, but I think you should move that to ~/bin/mate instead of ~/bin/mate/mate. If the system put it there, use this:

```
ln -s ~/bin/mate/mate ~/bin/mate
```

else just move it:

```
mv ~/bin/mate/mate ~/bin/mate
```

You should also check your PATH. If you didn't already know, the PATH tells the system what executables to execute.

```
PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
```